# Kineticjs - Filter + Crop

Tags: kineticjs

(I use Kinetic 4.6.0)

Is it a bug ? When y apply a crop on an image, all is good, like this :
[image with crop](http://www.netambition.eu/temp/kinetic_1.jpg)
But if I use a filter, there is the result :
[image with crop + filter](http://www.netambition.eu/temp/kinetic_2.jpg)
Proportions are not good. All the image is compress for entering in width and height of the crop.

Some ideas ?

My code for crop :

```csharp
this.imageFond = new Kinetic.Image({
    image               : this.imageObj,
    //filter            : Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
    //filterRadius      : 20
});
this.imageFond.setCrop([50,50,750,1100]);
this.imageFond.setWidth(750);
this.imageFond.setHeight(1100);

this.layer.add(this.imageFond);
this.layer.batchDraw();
```

My code for crop + filter :

```csharp
this.imageFond = new Kinetic.Image({
    image               : this.imageObj,
    filter              : Kinetic.Filters.Blur,
    filterRadius        : 20
});
this.imageFond.setCrop([50,50,750,1100]);
this.imageFond.setWidth(750);
this.imageFond.setHeight(1100);

this.layer.add(this.imageFond);
this.layer.batchDraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

The filters are not working correctly for cropped images. I made this pull request to fix it a while back. It hasn't been merged, so you need to apply it yourself. This at least fixed the problem for me. Hope this helps:

[Pull request to fix filters for cropped images](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/pull/435)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not get it to work with the kineticjs v4.6.0. 
I have merge your Image prototype with original but I have this error :
`IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`
`context.drawImage(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6], a[7], a[8]);`
Is there a mistake with scale ?

Comment: I just updated myself to 4.7 and need to merge. I'll let you know if I get it working. Please do the same if you get it working! Too bad it wasn't merged to the master.